# Unbound DNS caching server not loging

Tags: centos, dns

I am using the latest version of Centos.
I have installed and configured Unbound for caching DNS. Testing it from client computers with `dig` and `nslookup` works.

However, if I set `logfile` in `/etc/unbound/unbound.conf` I can't see any logs.  I have disabled Selinux and firewall.

When I debug this, there is a message in `/var/log/messages`:

```
error Could not open logfile /var/log/unbound: Permission denied
```

Also haven't any syntax error on the main configuration file of unbound

Now I try to solve this problem but I can't

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running `unbound` in a `chroot`? If so, is `/var/log/messages` available in that `chroot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's your `logfile` value? Am I right to assume it involves `/var/log/unbound` being a directory?

If so, make sure that directory exists, and that unbound runtime user may write in there.

```
mkdir -p /var/log/unbound
chown unbound:unbound /var/log/unbound
```

Otherwise, you may need to create unbound log file and set its permissions prior to starting unbound

```
touch /var/log/unbound
chown unbound:unbound /var/log/unbound
```

Comment: This Permission denied error is related to file ownership, but also directory ownership. Even if you chown unbound:unbound, there is a chance the permissions on /var/log/ might prevent unbound from writing to the file in that directory. Just another FYI for those who run into this issue. Personally I just redirected unbound.log to be located in /var/tmp/ because I'm the only person administering the server its running on.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it may not help. But i found a solution on another site.
[Unbound DNS caching server not loging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346122/unbound-dns-caching-server-not-loging).

Brief commands, if Link doesn't work.
The permissions on the file are okay, but the problem was with apparmor.

So to fix the issue, we have to edit the settings:

```
vim /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.unbound
```

Add this line (Here you should write a path to your "unbound.log" file. ):

```
# Site-specific additions and overrides for usr.sbin.unbound.
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.
/var/log/unbound/unbound.log rw,
```

Reload apparmor config and restart unbound services:

```
apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound 
service unbound restart
```

It helps me, hope it helps you too.

Comment: This worked on Debian 10. One note though - the link in your 1st paragraph points to this site. Can you fix that?